# regex with space or not at the end?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex to discover images in a text.

```
 if(preg_match('/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))\s+/', $titulo, $matches)){
    $titulo = str_replace($titulo, $matches[0], "<img src=\"$matches[0]\">");
 }
```

it will find images url and change the first match into an image.

it works ok but only if the url has another word after it.

```
http://example.com/image.jpg- not working
http://example.com/image.jpg text. - work
http://example.com/image.jpgtext - not working
```

I'd like to make it work in the 3 examples above. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing `\s+` to `\s*` as of instead "1 and more" to "0 and more"

Comment: Or just get rid of `\s+`

Comment: @Justinas yes, it will have the same result.

Comment: \s+ to \s* not working too :(

Comment: I feel the last `\s+` should be replaced with `(?!\S)`. Or removed altogether.

Comment: Try adding the global modifier /g and also remove the \s+

Comment: @bruno.bologna You mean to suggest `preg_match_all`, `g` modifier is not supported by PHP regex.

Comment: Are you sure you want `http://example.com/image.jpgtext`? If you're really being that lenient with the file names, might as well just use `https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif).*/

Answer (score 0):

In order to make these 3 extensions work, you should simply get rid of the `\s+`. Here is an example:

[image]